# Temperature ceasing

Tags: temperature

I'd like to ask this: since temperature is basically the motion of molecules, faster movement of molecules corresponds to higher temperature.

Now if some force is applied to each of them, will they stop their motion at the same time. Does it mean that the temperature will immediately drop to absolute zero?

On the other hand, if some force is used to speed up molecules, will it raise the temperature?

Comment: Atomic motion can't be fully stopped, but we can slow them down to create a  very low temperature: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_cooling